# jQuery getJSON is throwing error?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, cakephp

I am using the getJSON function in a file to get JSON from an api I am creating but the getJSON always enters my error handler for some reason. The code for the javascript is here. It always enters the .error function.

```
    window.onload = function() 
            {
                var data = "store_id=5";
                $.getJSON('http://localhost:81/javascript_plugin/get_store_items', data,
                function(json) {
                  alert(json);
                })
                .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
                .error(function() { alert("error"); })
                .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
            }
```

I am using CakePHP for my api side stuff and the file that is returned is shown below. $content_for_layout contains a JSON object created by calling "echo $js->object($json);" using the jQuery as the javascript engine. $json is a result of a CakePHP find call.

```
    <?php
         header("Pragma: no-cache");
         header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, must-revalidate"); 
         header('Content-Type: text/x-json'); 
         header("X-JSON: ".$content_for_layout);
         echo $content_for_layout; 
    ?>
```

When in Firebug the response code is 200 and the header contains all of the stuff shown but the response tab is empty. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using content-type: application/json? That is pretty much the standard content type for json.

Comment: If your php file isn't returning anything, then getJSON is going to throw an error (because there's no JSON there)

Comment: You're sure that `$content_for_layout` is getting set?

Comment: "application/json" has the same problem. When I open this url in a browser it downloads the file and opens it in JSON viewer which I have set to view JSON files. All my JSON I expect is there and looks fine. And yes $content_for_layout is set because the header X-JSON contains all of the JSON.

Comment: Run what you are outputting for $content_for_layout through JSLint.com to verify it is proper JSON. It may look right but there might be some syntax error that you are overlooking.

Comment: Try using the key-value type of data rather than the string form

Comment: JSLint.com returned "Problem at line 1 character 21: Missing space between ',' and 'page'." so there needs to be a space after all objects? JSONViewer as no problems parsing the JSON.

Comment: Could you update your question to show what the JSON is? JQuery uses a different parser (less forgiving) than JSONVier does since Jquery 1.5.

Comment: Try removing the header x-json call like  header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
 header("Pragma: no-cache");
 echo json_encode($content_for_layout);

Comment: OK well first thanks for all the comments. I have noticed that if I run the code in IE9 it works with jquery-1.4.4.min.js on client side. In Firebug the json variable in the callback says null. Any ideas why this would work in IE but not in Firefox?

Comment: Your json is not syntactically correct and needs to be fixed or you may end up having future issues with the code.

Comment: I will look at my JSON syntax but I am not actually creating it jQuery is by passing it to json_encode(). I was running the client script from a file, once I put it on a server there are no more problems anyway. Not sure why this is but it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was solved by moving the client side html file to my web server and running it from there. It seems that running a 'file://' html file will not allow this type of call to a server. Now all versions of jQuery work as well as all browsers.

Comment: When testing locally you should always be using some kind of webserver: webrick, mamp, etc. This is due to browser limitations for making requests to the file system as opposed to an http request.